# Laravel 5.2 Zizaco/entrust or spatie/laravel-permission

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-authorization

I'm new to Laravel and started a project. In the project I've to build a admin panel with user role and permission management. I've gone through few packages and selected these two. Which should I use in my project either [`Zizaco/entrust`](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust) or [`spatie/laravel-permission`](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission). I've gone through the docs of both but it will be great if you guys please provide me some sort of tuts if available for the package so that I can understand it clearly.

Comment: Did you get to any conclusion?

Answer (score 1):

I may be late to answer this, but I was looking for the same. I think this might help you [Two Best Laravel Packages to Manage Roles/Permissions](https://laravel-news.com/two-best-roles-permissions-packages)